# Error when trying to use functions from dlls

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

My code:

dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void F1()
{
    cout << "It works\n";
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int F2()
{
    return 154827;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void F3(int n)
{
    cout << "It works: "<<n<<"\n";
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int F4(int n)
{
    return n+1;
}
```

console application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef void (WINAPI*f1)();
typedef int (WINAPI*f2)();
typedef void (WINAPI*f3)(int);
typedef int (WINAPI*f4)(int);

#define MAXMODULE 50

f1 F1;
f2 F2;
f3 F3;
f4 F4;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HINSTANCE hLib=LoadLibrary("dllll.dll");

    if(hLib==NULL)
    {
        cout << "Unable to load library!" << endl;
        getch();
        return;
   }

    char mod[MAXMODULE];

   GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)hLib, (LPTSTR)mod, MAXMODULE);
   cout << "Library loaded: " << endl;


    F1=(f1)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "F1");
    F2=(f2)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "F2");
    F3=(f3)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "F3");
    F4=(f4)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "F4");

   if((F1==NULL) || (F2==NULL) || (F3==NULL) || (F4==NULL)) {

        cout << "Unable to load function(s)." << endl;
        FreeLibrary((HMODULE)hLib);
        return;
   }

   F1();
   cout<<F2()<<endl;
   F3(1515);
   cout << F4(12) << endl;   //works now :)

   FreeLibrary((HMODULE)hLib);

   getch();

    return;
}
```

Output:

```
Library loaded:
154827
It works
It works: 1515
```

Questions:
1. Why is F1 displayed after F2? F1 is called before F2.
2. F3 Works properly but makes a window pop up twice. I click Ignore on it.
[image]
<sub>(source: [ifotos.pl](http://s3.ifotos.pl/img/f3_hwpwapq.jpg))</sub>

3. Why F4 doesn't work at all? It raises an exception.

EDIT:
Question 2 and 3 are solved now.

For 1, output now is:

```
Library loaded:  
154827  
13  
It works  
It works: 1515
```

Which is in order: F2, F4, F1, F3.
I call them: F1, F2, F3, F4.
Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's likely happening is that your DLL and your executable are linking against different versions of the C++ runtime library.  Since there are now two different versions of the C++ runtime library living in your process's address space, there are two separate memory buffers being used for stdout.  Since you're not flushing the data inside your DLL functions but you *are* flushing it in your executable (note that printing a new line `'\n'` doesn't flush, but printing a `std::endl` *does* flush), this is what happens:

1. F1 is called, and `"It works\n"` gets written into your DLL's libc++ stdout memory buffer.
2. F2 is called, and `154827\n` gets written into your executable's libc++ stdout memory buffer.  The call to `std::endl` flushes that buffer and prints it to the console.
3. F3 is called, and `"It works: 1515\n"` gets written into your DLL's libc++ stdout memory buffer.
4. F4 is called, and `13` gets written into your executable's libc++ stdout memory buffer.  The call to `std::endl` flushes that buffer and prints it to the console.
5. Your process exits, causing your DLL to get unloaded.  As part of its cleanup routine, libc++ flushes its output buffers, causing `"It works\nIt works: 1515\n"` to get printed to the console.

This fix for this is to make sure that you're using the same C++ (and C) runtime libraries in your DLL and in your executable.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details on that—I recommend using the multithreaded release DLL version (`/MD` compiler option) for both the executable and DLL.

See also [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the wrong calling convention. Try changing `WINAPI` (which is `__stdcall`) to `__cdecl`.

```
typedef void (__cdecl *f1)();
typedef int (__cdecl *f2)();
typedef void (__cdecl *f3)(int);
typedef int (__cdecl *f4)(int);
```